# Как получить родительскую категорию у подкатегории первого уровня?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня сайт интернет магазин.
Есть товары. У товаров своя таблица Товары.
У каждого товара есть категория. Есть отдельная таблица с Категориями. Есть категории, есть подкатегории(больше ничего, 1 уровень).
Я их разделяю по parent_id, просто записываю у каждой подкатегории ее основную категорию.

При создании товара администратор указывает у товара подкатегорию, в бд у товара я записываю подкатегорию, но при выводе мне нужно показать ее родительскую категорию(название), которая связана по parent_id.

пишу на php pdo mysql, как можно сделать такую связь?

Думал может так сделать, но не работает. Ничего не выводится, что за ошибка сам не могу понять. Хотя вроде все правильно.

```html
$status = 0; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT categories.name, tovar.status, tovar.created_at, tovar.categories_id
FROM tovar 

LEFT JOIN categories c ON (tovar.categories_id = c.id)
LEFT JOIN categories pc ON (c.parent_id = pc.id)

WHERE tovar.status = :status ORDER BY tovar.created_at DESC");
$stmt->execute(array(':status' => $status));
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
     print_r($row);
   }
```

данные в бд есть. пример:

```html
таблица tovar
id categories_id 
1  3

таблица categories
id name parent_id
1  Машина    0
2  Вертолет  0
3  Большие машины   1
4  Маленькие машины   1
```

Есть товар, у которого указана подкатегория с id = 3, подкатегория 3 связана с родительской категорией 1, и нужно вывести название род. категории с id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял, у товара есть **id подкатегории**, а в таблице подкатегории есть **id главной категории**, название которой вам и надо вытащить.

Скажем есть таблицы: **products, categories, subcatigories**

SQL запрос:
`SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id_categories = (SELECT parent_id FROM subcatigories WHERE id_subcatigories = (SELECT subcatigories_id FROM products WHERE id = 1))`

Надеюсь, я правильно понял проблему и смог вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо. Только у меня 2 таблицы, не хотелось бы создавать доп таблицу для подкатегорий. Можно как то сделать в 2 таблицы?

Comment: @timursites я не особо понимаю структуру бд, можно и с 2-мя таблицами, но у вас написано, что есть товар (это 1 таблица), в котором написан id **подкатегории** (это 2 таблица), а в подкатегориях есть id родителя (это 3 таблица), имя которой и надо вытащить.

Если вы говорите, что у вас 2 таблицы, распишите более подробно что вы хотите

Comment: Есть две таблицы, Товары и таблица Категорий.
В таблице Категорий есть родительские категории и подкатегории.
Единственная разница это то что у подкатегорий указан parent_id. По которому можно понять какая родительская категория указана у подкатегории.

Comment: @timursites в таком случае, вам стоит делать проверку после первого запроса **select * from categories where id = 3**
````IF *id_parent запроса* >0 -> *новый запрос* select name from categories where id = *ранее полученный id_parent* ELSE *name запроса*```

Answer (score 0):

На примере `postgresql`. Думаю легко адаптируете под свои нужды

[image: Таблица tovar]

[image: Таблица categories]

Таблица `tovar` содержит

| id | categories_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Решетка радиатора |

Таблица `categories` содержит
|id|parent_id|name             |
|--|---------|-----------------|
|1 |null     |Машины           |
|2 |null     |Вертолеты        |
|3 |1        |Большие машины   |
|4 |1        |Маленькие машины |

Тогда нужный Вам `sql`-запрос будет выглядеть так

```sql
SELECT tovar.categories_id,
       (SELECT c.parent_id
        FROM categories c 
        WHERE c.id = tovar.categories_id) as parent_id, 
       (SELECT c2.name 
        FROM categories c1 
        LEFT JOIN categories c2 on c2.id = c1.parent_id
        WHERE c1.id = tovar.categories_id) as category, 
        tovar.name as tovar_name
FROM tovar
```

Результат

| categories_id | parent_id | category | tovar_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | Машины | Решетка радиатора |